# Android Java Shared Preferences push notification once

Tags: java, android, notifications, save

I have this inside `myMainActivity`:

```
public void sendNotificationIfTimeEnd01() {
    Intent intent01 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent01 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent01, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent01);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    builder.setContentTitle(gamesJuliToStringArray[0]);
    builder.setContentText("Ready");
    builder.setSubText("click for google");
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
            NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_01, builder.build());
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I call it inside my fragment like this:

```
if (diffDays <= 0) {
    String diffDaysAvailable = "ready";
    ((TextView) android.findViewById(R.id.readyLeft)).setText(diffDaysAvailable);
    ((TextView) 
    activity.sendNotificationIfTimeEnd01();
    Log.d("MyApp", "notification 1");
}
```

I basically get a sample notification if `diffDays <= 0`.
That works so far.

The problem is that the notification always pops up, when I restart the app.

I googled and read that one should use shared preferences to solve this issue.
(Not experienced with it).
I have this so far:

```
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        // push notification once time is up
        final String notification01 = sharedPreferences.getString("notification01", "not01");
```

But have no idea how to continue and solve this issue.

Comment: We can use `SharedPreferences`  for storing data. You can use `puXxxx()` to store and `getXxxx()`  to retrieve from it. Its not that complicated..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
if (diffDays <= 0) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final boolean notification01 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("notification01", false);

    if (!notification01) {
        String diffDaysAvailable = "ready";
        ((TextView) android.findViewById(R.id.readyLeft)).setText(diffDaysAvailable);
        activity.sendNotificationIfTimeEnd01();
        Log.d("MyApp", "notification 1");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("notification01", true);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Before sending any notification, this will check if the boolean is false or not. If it is false, then send the notification and set that boolean true, else nothing.

Comment: @KevinBrown I have explained.

Comment: Glad that helped. Do you mean you want to save the value of diffDaysAvailable instead of saving a boolean?

Comment: I mean I want to set the text of the button to ready like you wrote

        String diffDaysAvailable = "ready";
        ((TextView) android.findViewById(R.id.readyLeft)).setText(diffDaysAvailable);

but somehow this is now blank I guess its something if the condition

Comment: I got it was my fault

Answer (score 0):

This line initializes your `SharedPreference` with the name you provided and which will remain `Private` to your app

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Call this method when you want a `boolean` data is stored in preference which is associated with a key (a string literal).

```
public void setValue() {
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
 editor.putBoolean("your_key", true);
 editor.commit();
}
```

With this method you can check if you have already put a `true` value in your preference with a key.

```
public boolean isValueExists() {
 boolean value = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("your_key", false);
 return value;
}
```